# Querying single item in DynamoDB using Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a table in DynamoDB that stores some data, the partition key -  username - gets stored as the CognitoUser name along with a sort key provided by the user (Sort key is "Code") -  these make up the primary key.

I want to query a single Item in DynamoDB that matches the primary key.

Here is my Lambda function;

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const type = event.type;
    if (type === 'all'){
        const params = {
            TableName: 'test-record'
        };
        dynamodb.scan(params,function(err,data){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                callback(err);
            }else{
                console.log(data);
                const items = data.Items.map(
                    (dataField) =>{
                       return{
                           Date: dataField.Date.S,
                           Code: dataField.Code.S,
                           TelNumber: +dataField.TelNumber.N,
                           NameOfPerson: dataField.NameOfPerson.S,
                           FileNum: dataField.FileNum.S,
                           Purpose: dataField.Purpose.S,
                       };
                    }
                    );
                callback(null,items);
            }
        });
    }else if(type == 'single'){
        const params = {

            Key: {
                "username": {
                    S: dataField.username.S,
                },
                "Code": {
                    S: dataField.Code.S
                }
            },
            TableName: "test-record"  
        };
        dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err,data){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                callback(err);
            }else{
                console.log(data);
                callback(null, data);
            }
        });
    }else{
        callback('Something went wrong');
    } };
```

If i hardcode "username" and "Code" in this function, it works and returns the correct data, but using the above pasted code gives me an error saying;

```
{ "errorMessage": "RequestId: c410e493-b774-11e7-a528-37d94b51b57b Process exited before completing request" }
```

Any ideas how to get items from DynamoDB  without having to hard them into Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

One thing, I don't see how datafield is being initialized in the if(type == 'single') if statement outside of the map function... 
But aside from that, I think you should try using Expression Attributes names and values. I haven't tested this with getItem but it works for query:

I made the variable i used to get query the table from the my event body like:

```
const queryVariable = eval(JSON.stringify(e.body));
```

Then I used Expression Attributes and Expression Values in my params to make the query.

```
var params = {
  TableName: 'tablename',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#hkn = :v and begins_with(#sk, :skv)',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#hkn": "Hash_Key_Name",
    "#sk": "SortKeyName"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":qv": queryValue,
    ":skv": sortKeyValue
  }
}
```

### Then you can make your call to docClient.query(params, function(err, data) so on and so forth. Maybe you can use this instead of getItem.

But if you don't need to grab a single item and want to query your database for some variable keys, try this.

but a very simple Lambda function I've written to get data from DDB into a React Native Application goes like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-west-2'}); 

exports.handle = function(e, ctx, cb) {
  var params = { TableName: 'TableName' }; 
  docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) { 
      cb(err, null);
    } else { 
      cb(null, data.Items); 
    }
  });
}
```

Make sure the role being used to execute the lambda function include Dynamodb read access (at least)